# AngularJS modal dialog form object is undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, modal-dialog

We have a page that opens a modal dialog with a form like below. However when we hit the controller that should handle the form action, the form object is undefined and I am too much of an Angular newbie to understand why...

This is the parent page controller holds the function to open the modal dialog:

```
app.controller('organisationStructureController', ['$scope', ..., '$modal', function ($scope, ..., $modal) {

    $scope.openInvitationDialog = function (targetOrganisationId) {
      $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'send-invitation.html',
          controller: 'sendInvitationController',
          resolve: {$targetOrganisationId: function () {
            return targetOrganisationId;
          }
          }
        }
      );
    };
```

on a page like this:

```
// inside a loop over organisations
<a ng-click="openInvitationDialog({{organisation.id}})">Invite new member</a>
```

the invitation-dialog html looks like this:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- ... -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form name="invitationForm">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" style="color:white;">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="New member email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="invitation.email" required="true"/>
                        <span class="error animated fadeIn" ng-show="invitationForm.email.$dirty && invitationForm.email.$error.required">Please enter an email address!</span>
                        <span class="error animated fadeIn" ng-show="invitationForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ... -->

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendInvitation()">Invite</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The controller that should handle the invitation is somewhere else:

```
  app.controller('sendInvitationController', ['$targetOrganisationId', '$scope', ...,
    function ($targetOrganisationId, $scope, ...) {

    $scope.invitation = {
      // ...
      targetOrganisation: {
        id: $targetOrganisationId
      }
    };

    $scope.sendInvitation = function () {

      // $scope.invitationForm is undefined
      if ($scope.invitationForm.$invalid) {
        return false;
      }

      // send the invitation...

    };
  }]);
```

So what's the correct way to get the form scope into the controller?

Maybe I need to inject `$modal` into the `sendInvitationController` and add the `sendInvitation` function to it? But when I do that the action never enters the controller. Or do I have to add the function that handles the submit action to `$modal.open({ ...` instead of referencing the controller? Though I'd much prefer to have the sendInvitationController in its own file and scope.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

We found several things that helped us build a workaround and might help someone answer the question itself:

1. the `$scope.invitation` object is not undefined in the `sendInvitationController` but holds the correct data, while `$scope.invitationForm` remains undefined.
2. inside the send-invitation.html we can access `$scope.invitationForm.$invalid` and do the validation right there: `<button type="button" ng-click="sendInvitation()" ng-disabled="invitationForm.$invalid">Invite</button>`

So the question is: why does the binding of the `invitationForm` object to the `$scope` fail on submit while the form model binds correcetly?

Comment: I had similar issue - the problem is that $modal creates two scopes when creating a modal in this way - one for modal window purposes and another is yours. try to put dot in your ng-form expression - $scope.data = {} and then ng-form="data.invitationForm"

Comment: Why do not use `$dialog` with opt `backdropClick: false,`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @4avanger: Why would adding some dot notation help if there are two different scopes? I tried it but it just resulted in data being undefined instead of invitationForm. @Maxim: We're using $modal. Don't know what $dialog is, maybe it's the same? What does `backdropCLick: false` do?

Comment: @Pete Could you put your code (actually, a minimal part of it needed to reproduce the issue) in http://plnkr.co/. I know what your problem is and I see several other issues in your code snippet but it is kind of hard to explain without live code example.

Comment: Never used plunkr, but I can try.. Would be nice if you could check back on monday, since I'll be off work in less than an hour with a busy weekend ahead and I don't think I'll get my code working on plunkr in that time..

Comment: Found plunkr to be to much work to build up our setup.. But I added some important things we found out, which should narrow down the problem enough for anyone using angular for a while, I hope..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I had the same issue and could solve it by defining the form object in the scope of the modals controller. To get your code working put, for example, `$scope.form = {};` in the beginning of your controller and change your form tag to `<form name="form.invitation">`. Afterwards `$scope.form.invitation.$invalid` should be filled.

Comment: This also worked for me. I realize this is a scoping issue with modals, but is there a more elegant/Angular-like way of handing this?

Comment: @ErikOlson `$parent` scope is ideal for that, check my answer

Comment: this is owsm buddy :) thank you :). could u please explain what is the issue here :) thanks again

Answer (score 39):

**Update Nov 2014**: starting from angular-ui-bootstrap `0.12.0` transclusion scope is merged with the controller's scope. There is no need to do anything.

**Before 0.12.0**:

To put `invitationForm` directly in your parent controller scope you need to bypass transcluded scope this way:

```
<form name="$parent.invitationForm">
```

Above will automaticaly create form object in your parent controller. No need for pre-initialization stuff, long object paths or passing by event. Just access it with `$scope.invitationForm` once modal is opened.

Comment: The only working solution at this time (Angular 1.3) Please upvote !

Comment: I'm so happy I could kiss you!  You just made my day with this super easy solution!

Comment: Works Great in angular 1.2.x

Comment: `ui.bootstrap` `0.12.0` brings the fix, no need to use `$parent.` anymore

Answer (score 19):

The answer to the question of "Why?" is "scoping". **tl;dr** you created a new scope with the modal dialog which hid the scope's form object from your controller.

If we simplify your code, we roughly get the following:

```
<div ng-ctrl="organizeCtrl">
  <modal-dialog>
    <form name="invitationForm">
      <input type="email" ng-model="invitation.email" placeholder="Enter email..." />
      <input type="submit" ng-click="sendInvitation()" text="Invite!" />
      <input type="button" ng-click="cancel()" text="Cancel  :(" />
    </form>
  </modal-dialog>
</div>
```

(This is a very simplified version which *should* still have all of the core components.) Now, let's look at where scopes are created and what is injected in them.

```
<div ng-ctrl="sendInvitationController">
<!-- scope created above with "invitation" and "sendInvitation" from sendInvitationController -->
  <modal-dialog>
  <!-- scope created above for the modal dialog transclude -->
    <form name="invitationForm">
    <!-- add "invitationForm" to the modal dialog's scope -->
      <input type="email" ng-model="invitation.email" placeholder="Enter email..." />
      <input type="submit" ng-click="sendInvitation()" text="Invite!" />
      <input type="button" ng-click="cancel()" text="Cancel  :(" />
    </form>
  </modal-dialog>
</div>
```

Here, you can see that there is a new child scope created at the `<modal-dialog>` element and *that* is where the `invitationForm` object is actually added. That is why you can't see the object in the `sendInvitationController` but you can see it on the buttons for `ng-disabled`. If you want to be able to access the form construct outside of the `<modal-dialog>` element (e.g. in the `sendInvitationController`) you will need to pass that in the function call:

```
<div ng-ctrl="organizeCtrl">
  <modal-dialog>
    <form name="invitationForm">
      <input type="email" ng-model="invitation.email" placeholder="Enter email..." />
      <input type="submit" ng-click="sendInvitation(invitationForm)" text="Invite!" />
      <input type="button" ng-click="cancel()" text="Cancel  :(" />
    </form>
  </modal-dialog>
</div>
```

With the controller accepting the invitation form as a parameter to the `sendInvitation` function:

```
app.controller('sendInvitationController', ['$targetOrganisationId', '$scope', ...,
  function ($targetOrganisationId, $scope, ...) {
  $scope.invitation = {
    targetOrganisation: {
      id: $targetOrganisationId
    }
  };
  $scope.sendInvitation = function (form) {
    if (form.$invalid) {
      return false;
    }
    // send the invitation...
  };
}]);
```

@Robin identified the other solution, specifically to create an object rooted in the scope of the `sendInvitationController` and then attach the form directly to that object, relying on Angular's scope traversal mechanism to find the `form` object on the scope outside of the `<modal-dialog>` and attach the form object to that. Note that if you did not specify `$scope.form = {}` in the `sendInvitationController`, Angular would have created a new object for `form` on the scope for the `<modal-dialog>` and you still would not have been able to access it in the `sendInvitationController`.

Hopefully this helps you or other people learning about Angular scoping.

Comment: Great Explanation indeed! Easy to understand :)

Comment: This explanation is useful where based on submit button click, some DOM modifications in parent scope is required.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to work like this:

```
$modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'send-invitation.html',
  controller: 'sendInvitationController',
  scope: $scope // <-- I added this
}
```

No form name, no `$parent`. I'm using AngularUI Bootstrap version 0.12.1.

I was tipped off to this solution by [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2110#issuecomment-54551321).

Answer (score 0):

```
$mdDialog.show({
                locals: {alert:"display meassage"},
                controller: DialogController,
                templateUrl: 'views/dialog.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose:true,
                backdrop: true,
                keyboard: true,
                backdropClick: true,

            })
```