# Scope issues with $modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I am using a factory to open different forms in a modal dialog. in the modal-dialog's controller I check if the form is $valid before proceeding with my action's logic.

this was working file with ui-bootstrap $dialog (version 0.5.0) but when upgraded to using the $modal (0.9.0) this no longer works and i'm getting $scope.myForm.$valid = undefined.

I've tried using the $rootScope and passing the $scope from the calling controller but neither work.

Here is a plunker I've created to replicate the issue: (pop open the dialog and hit the Save button)

http://plnkr.co/edit/hLKob1LTzVs8GpOn5vmW?p=preview

can anyone suggest the best way to resolve this?

Thanks,
N

Comment: @its not good idea to pass `$scope` to service as argument. You brake Angular rules I think. Services are Singleton.

Comment: @MaximShoustin has a point.  I'd use `resolve` to share any variables that need sharing.

Comment: See gertas answer in this post, very simple and efficient:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312936/angularjs-modal-dialog-form-object-is-undefined-in-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code boils down to that `myForm` simply doesn't exist in the scope you expect it to.

You only get the `undefined` result because you earlier define `myForm` to be an empty object with `$scope.myForm = {};`. When you remove that line, your error will be `Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined`, as `myForm` in your scope has no relation at all to the form in the modal.

#### So where is the form?

The form exists in it's own scope, nested within the scope you expected it to live in. Confused yet?

[image]

#### So how do I access my form?

It is easy to communicate from a child (the scope that holds your form) to a parent, but not the other way around (at least to my knowledge). So you could simply define a method in `ModalInstanceCtrl` to store a reference to your form like so:

```
var myForm = null;

$scope.storeForm = function(form) {
  myForm = form;
}
```

Then invoke that method from within your template `myForm.html` with `{{storeForm(myForm)}}`.

You can then access `myForm.$valid` in your `scope.save()` method to check if it is valid.

Alternatively, you could pass parameters through the `save()` invocation itself, like so: `save(myForm)`.

Comment: or just `var myForm = $scope.$$childTail.myForm;`

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/IvSKpn3OJMp5E0yEkdIu?p=preview

Change

```
$scope.form.myForm = {};
```

To

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.form.myForm = {};
```

And it works.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: or simply `$scope.form = { myForm: {} };`

Comment: Out of curiosity, besides potential readability issues (they're both readable to me) are those two initializations equally efficient?

Comment: I doubt there's a noticeable performance difference. The one I posted is less typing? Minifies smaller?

Comment: your answer is correct, my plunker isn't - I guess I over simplified this scenario but my service is used from a controller of another directive with its own child scope and that is when things break. I will need to fix the plunker to reflect that.

Comment: I'd assume Shmiddty's alternative is a bit more efficient as there are less property lookups, but we'd be talking about microseconds here.

Comment: my plunker is updated. the issue is that the form object is not accessible from the modal's controller and therefore i'm getting: $scope.myForm.$valid  = undefined