# Submit form in AngularJs Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to submit a simple form with input in a modal (popup) written in AngularJs:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $modal) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

        if (toState.name == 'statePopup') {

            $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'popup.html',
                controller : 'AllegatiController',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });

            event.preventDefault();

        } else {

            return;
        }
    })
})
```

The form html is :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>File Name:</label> 
        <input type="text"  ng-model="name"></input>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

</form>
```

in my controller.js : the $scope.name came undefined

Updated:

This is my controller:

```
function myController($scope) {
    console.log("all myController");


     $scope.save = function() {

        var name= $scope.name;
        console.log('name is '+name);


    }
}
```

Maybe seems that in the run of the model which is defined for all the app missed the $scope parameter ?

What am i missed in my code?

Comment: where is you controller? where is `save()` method?

Comment: i updated my question with the controller

Comment: Check this demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/wJzt73GF9vdfi5vjTmi7?p=preview

Comment: ok , but i want to define my modal in the run function of the app in order to ensure the modal will open from anywhere in the app. I think that it missed the scope attribut in the modal but i don't know how to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by updated my ui-bootsrap version up from 0.12.0

This is a link that helped me:

[Link angularJs modal submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312936/angularjs-modal-dialog-form-object-is-undefined-in-controller)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
$modal.open({
    templateUrl : 'popup.html',
    controller : 'AllegatiController',
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

your controller should be:

```
myApp.controller('AllegatiController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    console.log('all myController');

    $scope.save = function () {
       var name = $scope.name;
       console.log('name is '+name);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: yes it's like this but with a different definition , the app can recognize the controller, the issue that when i submit the form in the modal, the value doesn't pass to the controller